# Extract a particular character from a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I want to extract the episode number from the name of TV Series.

e.g. If it is "**Game of Thrones S06E01**", Then I should get 01.

What I am trying is :

1. First see if the string contains something like "S__E__"(e.g "Blacklist **S01E05**")
2. If yes, then see what's there after "E" or "e", and extract it.

But due to variation in types of inputs, I can get different names to check like :

1. Blacklist S01E01
2. Blacklist s01e01 (small "e" and "s")
3. Blacklist S1E1
4. Blacklist S01E01.mkv
5. Se7en S01E01

and so on...

Comment: nuber will be same between s and e?

Comment: yes those could also change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Praise the power of **regular expressions** then:

```
\b(?i)S\d+E(\d+)(?i-)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kM0fL4/2).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
Blacklist S01E01
Blacklist s01e01 (small "e" and "s")
Blacklist S01E01.mkv
Se7en S01E01
DATA;

$regex = '~\b(?i)S\d+E(\d+)(?i-)\b~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

And see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/O0XfWa).

---

Updated: To do it in `jQuery/JavaScript`, you need to change the inline modifiers:

```
\bS[\d.]+E(\d+)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kM0fL4/4) (and mind the modifiers!).

Comment: very fast and quick +10

Comment: This is nice cause it works for `Game.Of.Thrones.S01E01.mkv` and `Game.Of.Thrones.S01E1.mkv` too. +1

Comment: Quick note: it won't work if there is also a `.` between `S01` & `E01`.

Comment: @FirstOne: Is this often? One could use a character class then `[\d.]+`.

Comment: I'm not the op.. I've just seen a lot of series names ;)

Comment: is regex same to do it in jquery?

Comment: @FirstOne: I'd better not ask ***where*** ;-)

Comment: @FirstOne: See the updated expression on https://regex101.com/r/kM0fL4/4

Comment: @Jan the jquery solution do not work for "dead.of.summer.s01e01.proper.480p.mkv" . any suggestions? I am doing like this : `var res = str.match(/\bS[\d.]+E(\d+)\b/gi);
alert(res[1]);`

Comment: @Jan , what about S01 E03 ? (If there are whitespaces)

Comment: or "BlacklistS01E03"? ( if there are no spaces)

Comment: Just ask another question and provide all examples you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
<?php

$movie = 'Game.Of.Thrones.S01E01.mkv';

$exp = "/([Ss][0-9]+)([Ee])([0-9]+)/";

preg_match_all($exp, $movie, $result);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result[count($result) - 1][0]);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```